# how to check if a presentation is 2007 or 2010?

Tags: c#, interop, powerpoint, office-interop

I need to find if a presentation was made using PowerPoint 2010 or 2013, in order to look for certain features in the presentation that only apply to PowerPoint 2013 (for example YouTube embedded videos).

I am using  interop and c# to look at the presentation.

thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll notice it with the GUID from the Powerpoint, it is different from one version to another one. If you plan to write some Add-Ins, you'll notice it. Been writing one for 2007-2010, and it didn't work on 2013. http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/vstudio/system.guid.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I found that there is this tag chartTrackingRefBased preProps.xml, that is only used by the 2013 version of powerpoint.

Comment: But this is not really a answer.